# How to find the number of x-length walks between two vertices of a triangle

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

This question is from my homework and I don't have any idea how to solve it. Find the number of 2019-length walks between two vertices of a triangle.

Comment: Try it for walks of length $5$.

Answer (score 1):

Pick one vertex as the starting vertex.  Let $A(n)$ be the number of walks of length $n$ that end at that vertex.  Let $B(n)$ be the number of walks of length $n$ that end at a specific other vertex.  Write a set of coupled recurrence relations involving them and solve them.  Note that the number of walks ending at the third vertex is also $B(n)$.  As you have two choices at each point, you must have $A(n)+2B(n)=2^n$

Answer (score 0):

From each vertex of the triangle, you always have two choices, go left or go right (clockwise/anticlockwise).
Now say that you go $x$ times left and $y$ times right. Then $x + y = 2019$. Furthermore, you should take a look at $x-y$ (mod $3$) to arrive at the right vertex.

So the problem boils down to:

For every $0 < x < 2019$, check if $x - (2019 -x)$ (mod $3$) is as desired.
Can you count how many such $x$ you can find?

Once you have all your $x$, you need to decide how to divide them, so do you go first all $x$ then all $y$, or do you split them up somehow.

Comment: I think it should be like 2^2019. I was also wondering that why we don't diagonalize the adjacency matrix for finding solution.